# High charts undefined value on customizing tool tip - Unable to get the ID from array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to customize my tool-tip in high charts. I have the following map function:

```
let Data = types.map(function (obj) {
    return [obj.year, obj.value, obj.id]
    
});
```

Example output of the above is: [2000, 20, 5605]

In my highchart my x value is 2000 and my y value is 20. The 5605 is an ID that I want to display in my tooltip but I cant seem to access this ID. The way I use it in the highcharts is by doing the following:

```
series: [{
            name: "Linechart1",
            color: "#d8d6d3",
            data: Data,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 3
            }
        }]
```

and my tooltip customise functionality is the following. The [Insert ID here]:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            console.log(this);

            return ' (' + [Insert ID here] + ') ' + '<br />' + 'Year: ' + this.x + '<br />' + 'Value: ' + this.y;
        }
    }
```

How do I use my ID from Data array in my custom tool tip code? I tried this.ID but it doesnt work. Just says Undefined. I have a JS Fiddle to show my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/g96v1ptc/

In the above JS FIDDLE my data is as follows. Inside each is the following
[x,y,id]:

```
data: [[2010,43934,1], [2011,52503,5], [2012,57177,7], [2013,69658,10], [2014,97031,16], [2016,119931,45], [2018,137133,43], [2020,154175,19]]
```

I want my id to be added where it says 'ID HERE' in the tooltip. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keys` option to map elements from the array to point's properties:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return ' (' + this.point.customId + ') ' + '<br />' + 'Year: ' + this.x + '<br />' + 'Value: ' + this.y;
        }
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['x', 'y', 'customId'],
        data: [
            [2010, 43934, 1],
            ...
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/82wzsb4q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys